# "export 'createNetworkInterface' was not found in 'apollo-client'

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, apollo, vue-apollo

I did this sample: https://github.com/Akryum/vueconf-2017-demo

As a result, I have the same file in my project: https://github.com/Akryum/vueconf-2017-demo/blob/master/src/apollo-client.js

This is the code used in my application:

```
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client'

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    transportBatching: true,
  }),
  connectToDevTools: true,
})

export default apolloClient
```

As a result, I get this error (warning) to the console:

```
warning  in ./src/apollo/client.js

15:23-45 "export 'createNetworkInterface' was not found in 'apollo-client'
```

And this is from the browser console:

```
TypeError: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_apollo_client__["createNetworkInterface"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_apollo_client__["createNetworkInterface"])({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    transportBatching: true
  })', 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_apollo_client__["createNetworkInterface"])' is an instance of Object)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the version of `apollo-client` listed in your `package.json`?

Comment: @DanielRearden `^2.0.1`. And used `2.0.1` version.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like that repo hasn't been updated to use `apollo-client`'s latest version. The Apollo client underwent major changes in version 2.0. You can see a summary of those changes and an upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/recipes/2.0-migration.md). One of the breaking changes implemented was a switch from `NetworkInterface` to `ApolloLink`, which is why you are seeing an error that `createNetworkInterface` cannot be found.

Either downgrade to version 1.9.3

```
npm install apollo-client@1.9.3
```

or follow the upgrade guide in the link above to see how to use version 2.0 in your project.

Comment: apollo 2 is still unstable, and maybe take a lot of weeks to get stable in final version, better use still 1.9.3

Comment: Link is broken, this one might help: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/recipes/2.0-migration.md

Answer (score 9):

Since Version 2.x Apollo has deprecated NetworkInterface in favor of Apollo Link, this unfortunately is a breaking change.

To get your code working again you would need to make the following changes,

replace

```
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client'
```

with

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
```

add

```
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
```

and run

```
npm install --save apollo-link-http
```

replace

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    transportBatching: true,
  }),
  connectToDevTools: true,
})
```

with

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'
  }),
  connectToDevTools: true,
})
```

and don't forget to export your function

```
export default apolloClient
```